# How do you get view hierarchy in Android or Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am using Android Espresso and when it cannot find a match, it will throw an exception with printing the view hierarchy. Is there a way to get this kind of view hierarchy dynamically when you are running Android testing or Espresso

```
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800,     has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909225, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=764, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=36.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131427395, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=764, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Android `View hierarchy` is a tree structure and it is easier to iterate through each tree node using some sort of algorithms, you can view those method at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/util/TreeIterables.html

The way it prints out the Exception trace uses a method called `breadthFirstViewTraversal`and print out view tree in class `ViewFinderImpl`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/base/ViewFinderImpl.html

Comment: Can I ask an extra question of how to get the current activity in order to get the root view to pass to the function?

Answer (score 10):

You can cause a exception and View Hierarchy will appear. For example put this in your test file:

```
onView(withText("XYZ")).perform(click())
```

and since text XYZ does not exists, result will be:

```
...espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "XYZ"

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1024, height=600, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1024, height=600, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`HumanReadables.getViewHierarchyErrorMessage` is what Espresso uses to print the graph when view matcher fails, so instead of throwing a bogus match and catching it, just:

```
\\ import androidx.test.espresso.util.HumanReadables
val theRootView = fragment.view
val viewHierarchy: String = HumanReadables.getViewHierarchyErrorMessage(theRootView, null, "", null)
```

You need a to pass a View in.  For example, if you're working with a Fragment, the `fragment.view` will be the root of the graph.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer specially to add more details and explain why your answer fix the issue ?